# Google Play Games error with Unity - "There are no public high score for this game"

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have the same problem as this ([Google Play Games - "There are no public high score for this game"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72487221/google-play-games-there-are-no-public-high-score-for-this-game/75820081?noredirect=1#comment133743304_75820081)) but as it was not answered by anyone I couldnt figure out any answers.

I am using Easy Mobile Pro with Unity.

I do get the debug: "Reported score successfully" but when I open the leaderboard but it is completely empty with the message: "There are no public high scores for this game."

Any help is appreciated.

this is my code for the show leaderboard:

```
else if (buttonName == "ButtonLeaderBoard")
        {
            Debug.Log("Score:" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalratings"));
            Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
```

and this is my code to report the score to the leaderbaord:

```
if (!Application.isEditor)
            {
                Social.ReportScore(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalratings"), Common.gpHighScoresGlobalId, success =>
                {
                    Debug.Log(success ? "Reported score successfully" : "Failed to report score");
                });
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried authenticating first? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918657/unity-google-game-play-services-not-submitting-scores-to-leaderboard

Comment: yes i am authenticating the use and it works just fine, the google play games pop ups when i start the game 

'Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => {
            if (success)
            {
                Debug.Log("Authentication successful");
                string userInfo = "Username: " + Social.localUser.userName +
                    "\nUser ID: " + Social.localUser.id +
                        "\nIsUnderage: " + Social.localUser.underage;
                Debug.Log(userInfo);
            }
            else
                Debug.Log("Authentication failed"); '